# including html tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add nested html tags using jquery...How to include html tags with span in jquery style for the below code?

```
<adiv>               
    <bdiv id="9" class="class1">
        <span class="class2"> jquery CSS<span>
    </bdiv>     
</adiv>
```

Comment: is the provided code the goal or the basis? i dont understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what I think you mean:

```
$(".class1").find("span.class2").html("<strong>HTML</strong> added to the inner <em>span</em>");
```

But `adiv` and `bdiv` are not semantic mark-up, just use `div`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tag named adiv and bdiv but if you really want to add them into your html, you can do it with;

```
var adiv = $('<adiv>')
var bdiv = $('<bdiv>',{id:9, class:'class1'})
var span = $('<span>',{class:'class2', text:'jquery CSS'})

span.appendTo(bdiv);
bdiv.appendTo(adiv);
```